# Angular 2 *ngFor Display clickable email address as part of table data

Tags: html, email, angular, typescript, ngfor

In my typescript I have an array of objects:

```
array: [
 {
   prop1: 'string1',
   prop2: this.createEmailLink('email@email.com'),
   prop3: 'string2'
 },
 {
   // next object
 }
]
```

I also have a function which turns this into a value only array, so I can use *ngFor in the  element and reuse the table code on other pages. After going through that function the resulting array is:

```
array: [
  ['string1', 'emailaddress', string2'], 
  [//next object]
]
```

My html code creates the rows and columns in an ng-container:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of array>
 <tr class="some-class">
    <td *ngFor="let column of row">{{column}}</td>
 </tr>
</ng-container>
```

This all works fine except that I need the email address to be clickable (href="mailto:..."). I created a function, this.createEmailLink(email), in my typescript file that converts the email address to a string.

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a>
```

However, this generated string is displayed as it appears above and not as rendered html.

I have searched here and have seen similar cases that involve innerHtml but I have yet to find an answer to my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `createEmailLink` function returns HTML as a string you will need to bind to the `innerHTML` property as you have read before. This can be done as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of array>
 <tr class="some-class">
    <td *ngFor="let column of row">
        <div [innerHTML]="column"></div>
    </td>
 </tr>
</ng-container>
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mi5BnbXvOK6MFC8XVzZV)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly the explanation I needed. The demo is much appreciated.